# Child bindinglist changes not propagating to corresponding bindingsource

Tags: .net, bindingsource, bindinglist

I have a class, Sample, with a child class, SampleTests.  In a presenter class, I have BindingList(Of Sample) property, CurrentSamples.  The presenter also has an AddTest method which adds a test to a specified sample in the bindinglist.

In a form, there is a SampleBindingSource that is bound to the presenter's CurrentSamples property.  There is also a SampleTestBindingSource that takes the SampleBindingSource as its DataSource and has its DataMember set to SampleTest.

I have verified that when I use the AddTest method that the test is indeed added to that sample.  I have also verified that the SampleBindingSource has the added test by looping through the bindingsource records and counting the number of tests on each record.  However, if I display the number of records in the SampleTestBindingSource for the sample that has two tests, SampleTestBindingSource only shows one record/test.

I have tried ResetBindings on the presenter's bindinglist, on the SampleTestsBindingSource, and on the SampleBindingSource.  I have tried EndEdit on the two bindingsources as well. None of these attempts propogates the changes in SampleTests to the SampleTestsBindingSource.

How can I get the changes in the presenter to propogate all the way to the SampleTestsBindingSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution to a similar problem I had at a later date:

[Child bindingsource bound to child entityset does not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100229/child-bindingsource-bound-to-child-entityset-does-not-update/12272876#12272876)