# Child bindingsource bound to child entityset does not update

Tags: .net, winforms, linq-to-sql, bindingsource

I have a table, SampleData, that has a child table, Measurements.  On my WinForm, frmMain, a single SampleData object is bound to the SampleDataBindingSource; the MeasurementsBindingSource has SampleDataBindingSource as its datasource and Measurements as its DataMember.  A set of textboxes are bound to SampleDataBindingSource; a datagridview is bound to MeasurementsBindingSource.

For frmMain, I also have a presenter class, preMain, which contains a property, CurrentSample, of type SampleData.  The `SampleDataBindingSource.DataSource` is bound to the CurrentSample property of preMain.

When enough of the properties in Measurements have been assigned, it calculates the FiringFactor and, if the FiringFactor is not 1, it adds another Measurement item to the CurrentSample's Measurement entityset:

```vb
Partial Class Measurement

    Private Sub UpdateFiringFactor()
        Dim necessaryDataIsAvailable As Boolean = (Me.CrucibleMass IsNot Nothing And _
                                                   Me.CrucibleSampleFiredMass IsNot Nothing And _
                                                   Me.CrucibleSampleMass IsNot Nothing)
        If necessaryDataIsAvailable Then
            Me.FiringFactor = CDbl((Me.CrucibleSampleFiredMass - Me.CrucibleMass) / (Me.CrucibleSampleMass - Me.CrucibleMass))
            If Me.FiringFactor <> 1 Then
                Me.SampleData.AddNewMeasurement()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnCrucibleMassChanged()
        UpdateFiringFactor()
    End Sub


    Private Sub OnCrucibleSampleFiredMassChanged()
        UpdateFiringFactor()
    End Sub


    Private Sub OnCrucibleSampleMassChanged()
        UpdateFiringFactor()
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I enter values for CrucibleMass, CrucibleSampleMass, and CrucibleSampleFiredMass in the datagridview, the UpdateFiringFactor method does run correctly and I eventually get another Measurement item added to CurrentSample's Measurements entityset.  However, the datagridview does not show a new row and the MeasurementsBindingSource only has 1 record (but `CurrentSample.Measurements.Count = 2`).

Why does the change in `CurrentSample.Measurements` not propogate to `MeasurementsBindingSource`?  I have tried `MeasurementsBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)`, `MeasurementsDataGridView.Refresh`, `SampleDataBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)`, but nothing seems to update `MeasurementsBindingSource` or its datagridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I found to the entityset/bindingsource problem:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Partial Class Measurement

    Public Sub ChangeCrucibleMass(ByVal thisMass As Double)
        CrucibleMass = thisMass
        UpdateFiringFactor()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeCrucibleSampleMass(ByVal thisMass As Double)
        CrucibleSampleMass = thisMass
        UpdateFiringFactor()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeCrucibleSampleFiredMass(ByVal thisMass As Double)
        CrucibleSampleFiredMass = thisMass
        UpdateFiringFactor()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateFiringFactor()
        If AllDataAreAvailable() Then
            FiringFactor = (CrucibleSampleFiredMass - CrucibleMass) / (CrucibleSampleMass - CrucibleMass)
            Me.Sample.OnMeasurementsChanged(Nothing, Nothing)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function AllDataAreAvailable() As Boolean
        AllDataAreAvailable = False
        Dim allFieldsHaveValue As Boolean = (CrucibleMass IsNot Nothing And CrucibleSampleFiredMass IsNot Nothing And CrucibleSampleMass IsNot Nothing)
        If allFieldsHaveValue Then
            Dim denominatorIsNotZero As Boolean = (CrucibleSampleMass - CrucibleMass) <> 0
            Return denominatorIsNotZero
        End If

    End Function

End Class

Partial Class Sample

    Public Sub OnMeasurementsChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.PropertyChanged
        If Me.Measurements.Count > 0 AndAlso Me.Measurements.Last.FiringFactor IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.Measurements.Last.FiringFactor <> 1 Then
            Me.Measurements.Add(New Measurement With {.CrucibleMass = Me.Measurements.Last.CrucibleMass})
            RaiseEvent RefreshMeasurementsBinding()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnCreated()
        Me.Measurements.Add(New Measurement)
    End Sub

    Public Event RefreshMeasurementsBinding()

End Class
```

Here's a screenshot of the form:

[image]

And the code-behind:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents newSample As Sample

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        newSample = SampleConduit.GetSample(1)
        'newSample = New Sample
        Me.SampleBindingSource.DataSource = newSample
        OnRefreshMeasurementsBinding()

    End Sub

    Private Sub OnRefreshMeasurementsBinding() Handles newSample.RefreshMeasurementsBinding
        Me.MeasurementsBindingSource.DataSource = newSample.Measurements.GetNewBindingList
    End Sub


    Private Sub MeasurmentsDataGridView_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles MeasurmentsDataGridView.CellClick
        Me.MeasurementsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Dim currentMeasurement = CType(Me.MeasurementsBindingSource.Current, Measurement)
        Select Case e.ColumnIndex
            Case 0
                currentMeasurement.ChangeCrucibleMass(GetMeasurement)
            Case 1
                currentMeasurement.ChangeCrucibleSampleMass(GetMeasurement)
            Case 2
                currentMeasurement.ChangeCrucibleSampleFiredMass(GetMeasurement)
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Function GetMeasurement() As Double
        Return CDbl(InputBox("Measurement:", "Get Measurement", "0"))
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim currentSample = CType(Me.SampleBindingSource.Current, Sample)
        SampleConduit.SaveSample(currentSample)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The solution hinges on the RefreshMeasurementsBinding event in the Sample class and the OnRefreshMeasurementsBinding method in the form.  Frequently setting the MeasurementsBindingSource to the GetNewBindingList method on the Measurements entityset seems a bit kludgy, but it works.

See Item#3 about EntitySets and BindingSource and GetNewBindingList in this forum posting:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/43526.aspx